# Could not autowire field, but I have the definition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

My app-config.xml has a definition for my UserDao bean:

```
  <bean id="userDao" class="com.blah.core.db.hibernate.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

I have my component scanning:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah" />
```

My index action in my HomeController works fine (it outputs the contents of a method on my UserService to a freemarker template).

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;




    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView Index() {



        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        mav.setViewName("index");
        mav.addObject("message", userService.sayHello());

        mav.addObject("username", userService.getTestUser());


        return mav;
    }
```

The 'getTestUser()' is a new method that makes reference to UserDao, it looks like:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public String sayHello() {

        return "hello from user service impl part 2";

    }

    public String getTestUser() {


        return userDao.getById(1L).getUsername();

    }


}
```

I am getting the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.blah.core.db.hibernate.UserDao com.blah.core.services.UserServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.blah.core.db.hibernate.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

1. What could the issue be?
2. If I didn't do autowire, what would I be doing instead of adding the @AutoWire on the UserDao definition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried exporting all registered beans of Spring (or read [Spring's bootstrap log](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743) or the memory via [debugging](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2221711/Debugging-a-Java-Program-with-Eclipse.htm)) to find out if the `userDao` bean is in the list. Please make sure that `UserDaoImpl` is really implementing `UserDao` too - I am pointing at this because am not seeing the snippet of `UserDaoImpl` here.

If you do not use `@Autowired`, the alternative will be explicitly obtaining a reference of the bean through ApplicationContext's [getBean()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean(java.lang.String)) (which is considered as a dirty way, fix your `@Autowired` instead), via its bean name, class name, etc.

Comment: ok I wasn't implementing the UserDao ahh! thanks!  btw, how do you read spring's bootstrap log or the memory via debugging?)  Those are good skills I should learn!

Comment: I have updated the answer with references to logging and debugging. :)